# Manually edit DNS in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, dns

I have problem with network connection. Internet don't work but when I type `ping 8.8.8.8` in terminal it works.

So I called ISP and operator tell me that to change DNS but I don't know where it is.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to set a custom DNS on Ubuntu 14.04 (and other) is by editing the `base` file of the `resolv.conf.d` folder:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

Add your DNS to the file :

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Update `resolv` configuration :

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Comment: thanks but can you tell why this happened? I didn't change anything but this morning all phones and computers wouldn't connect to computer.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure to understand. You connect all your computers and phones to another computer ? I think it is a different problem. You should create a new question for that.

Comment: In my case the configured `nameserver` becomes the 3rd option at `/etc/resolv.conf`, not the primary. How to make it the primary (or maybe the only one)? I have an old system, I am not sure if there are DNS configurations on some other files.